# SDL (auto) keyboard input

Tags: c++, sdl

Is there a way for automatic key presses (not by user input)? For example, the right keyboard key is "pressed" when some condition is true.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Instead of forcing the api to do something its not designed for, its best to just call the same function that gets triggered when the key is pressed.

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: I haven't looked at the documentation in a while but I'm pretty sure there is a function to push your own events into eventqueue.

Comment: What do you mean with automatic key presses? Do you mean you want to automatically catch a signal or automatically generate it without the user having to push buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Just to save some googling time for other people, the official SDL docs have this example for [SDL_PushEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29):

```
// Default Usage:
SDL_Event sdlevent;
sdlevent.type = SDL_KEYDOWN;
sdlevent.key.keysym.sym = SDLK_1;

SDL_PushEvent(&sdlevent);
```